# Limit the max connections per IP using OpenWRT?

Tags: iptables, openwrt, routing

Would the following `iptables` command on an OpenWRT router assure that no one client has more than 50 active connections?

```
$ iptables -I FORWARD -m connlimit --connlimit-above 50 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
iptables v1.4.6: Couldn't load match `connlimit':File not found
```

If so, what package do I need to install to be able to use `--connlimit`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe it is in the standard distribution.  You will need to compile your own kernel.  There is [ticket with a patch](https://dev.openwrt.org/ticket/6168) already submitted.

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -s 192.168.1.10  -m connlimit --connlimit-above 20 -j DROP
```

Needs `iptables` `conntrak` extra package installed.